# Shifting C++ Compiler from Windows to Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, c++, mingw

While learning how to code in C++, I installed minGW to allow me to compile C++ code through IDEs and the command prompt. However, recently I have been trying to use the WSL for most of my tasks. While trying to compile a C++ file from the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS distro, I realized that while I do have the C++ compiler installed, since I did not do it through the terminal, it does not recognize the function (c++ -Wall -c HelloWorld.cpp) and gives me the error message "Command gcc not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install gcc"

I was wondering if there is some way to compile C++ files without having to reinstall the C++ compiler through the distro?

Comment: If you didn't run C++ through the terminal, how exactly, did you run it?  Your minGW instance/instalaltion isn't compatible with WSL.

Comment: I compiled and ran all my C++ files through the command prompt using the command mentioned in the question. Does this mean that in order to use the same functionality on WSL, I will have to install a C++ compiler for the subsystem as well using sudo apt install gcc?

Comment: Not certain how well `gcc` would work under WSL, but you might want to have a look at [this overview of running Windows commands in WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop#run-windows-tools-from-wsl). That pages also potentially covers using WSL binaries under "regular" Windows.

Comment: *gcc* absolutely can be installed on Linux which means it can be installed within a Wasal instance

Comment: Thank you for the replies.